# Set output of command as value of variable

Tags: bash

I want to determinate on my 4 nodes cluster which node is active.
I also want to put the name of current active node to script.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dev1=10.1.1.1
dev2=10.1.1.2
dev3=10.1.1.3
dev4=10.1.1.4
/usr/bin/ssh -x root@${dev1} $'command  | grep -Eo "active"'
/usr/bin/ssh -x root@${dev2} $'command  | grep -Eo "active"'
/usr/bin/ssh -x root@${dev3} $'command  | grep -Eo "active"'
/usr/bin/ssh -x root@${dev4} $'command  | grep -Eo "active"'
```

As a result I'd like to get this variable in this form (I would like to use it in the further part of the script) :

```
active=$dev2
```

Hers is my current output:

```
sh -x s.sh
+ dev1=10.1.1.1
+ dev2=10.1.1.2
+ dev3=10.1.1.3
+ dev4=10.1.1.4
+ /usr/bin/ssh -x root@10.1.1.1 'command | grep -Eo "active"'
+ /usr/bin/ssh -x root@10.1.1.2 'command | grep -Eo "active"'
+ /usr/bin/ssh -x root@10.1.1.3 'command | grep -Eo "active"'
active
+ /usr/bin/ssh -x root@10.1.1.4 'command | grep -Eo "active"
```

Comment: What if no node or multiple nodes are active?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is usually exactly one active host, but still safeguarding against the corner cases, you can write it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a dev             # hold hosts in indexed array
declare -i numActive=0     # hold number of active hosts in integer variable
declare -i lastActive=     # last active host while iterating

dev[1]=10.1.1.1
dev[2]=10.1.1.2
dev[3]=10.1.1.3
dev[4]=10.1.1.4

for(( i=1 ; i<=${#dev[@]} ; i++ )) ; do

  # execute command on that host:
  output=$( /usr/bin/ssh -x "root@${dev[$i]}" 'command' )

  # if the host is active, remember its index and 
  # increase the count of active hosts:
  if grep -qEo "active" <<< "$output" ; then
    lastActive="$i"
    numActive=$(( numActive + 1 ))
  fi
done

# depending on number of active hosts, print 
# "none", "multiple" or the active host's ip:

if [ "$numActive" -eq 0 ] ; then
  active="none"
elif [ "$numActive" -gt 1 ] ; then
  active="multiple"
else
  active=${dev[$lastActive]}
fi

echo "$active"
```

Note that I moved the `grep` to the client side. This may be a bad idea if `command` yields a large amount of output.